# how can i populate dictionary with contents of url .txt file

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I saved a dictionary contents in server and from server it automatically converted to `.txt` file how can i load that contents from url to another `NSDictionary`?

I am using this code:

```
NSDictionary *Data = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

**url is something like    https://www.example.com/files/admin.txt**

How do i load this to `NSDictionary`?

I am now getting null values
when i type the url in browser i get my file contents.

Comment: Post the code that you use to save the dictionary contents in the first place, or an example of a file that you try to create a dictionary from.

Comment: check question please

Comment: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/909-how-to-load-an-nsdictionary-object-from-a-web-site-into-an-iphone/

Comment: Why don't you finish the last topic by saying thanks to volunteers who answered your question and then marking a mark before opening a similar topic?

Comment: its not working so how do i say thanks ???????

Comment: Sorry hob am getting null

Comment: How is this dictionary created? This looks like a JSON dictionary to me, except the quotation marks are escaped. That may be one of the reasons you are getting null values.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer

```
 NSDictionary *dict;
    NSString *url=@"https://example.com/admin.txt";

    NSMutableDictionary *str=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    str=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSMutableArray *a=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [a addObject:[str objectForKey:@"Bookmarks"]];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *Path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Bookmarks.plist"];

    [a writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
```

thanks for your all help